# How do I set up an alias to email to multiple users?

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

I want to set up an alias "sa...@mydomain.com" to be forwarded to a couple Google Apps users, us...@mydomain.com & us...@mydomain.com.  I've looked everywhere in setup and cannot find how to do this.

That is y situation I didnt find yet a solution to this.  I've tried to using the pop option.

Right now I am stuck with doing the following:  I have the "sales@" alias received by us...@mydomain.com.  Then I use a filter to forward the "sales@" emails to us...@mydomain.com (leaving a copy on the server) while having us...@mydomain.com pull the mail from the user3 account via POP.  I have found that this is actually not reliable.

help?

Comment: Try putting them in a [Group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33329), with this people can then use a single address to send mail to the entire group, or invite the group to a meeting or to share a document.

Comment: Check out this Google Forum : [alias deliver to multiple 'real' accounts](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/apps/mail-settings/ufeZIvitoyU) and [alias to email to multiple users](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/K3yHLafUb2I) and this [question in serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/384144/can-i-have-one-alias-for-both-two-real-accounts-in-google-apps)